# Error with seek function in big files

Tags: lua

i've one question about lua and io library.

i've this simple function to get file size:

```
function checkisoLIMG(file)
    local iso = assert(io.open(file, "rb"));
    if (iso) then
        local size = iso:seek("end");
        iso:close();
        return size;
    else
        return "error";
    end
end
```

When i try to get the size of a big file (about 3GB or 4GB) the function return nil or -1, but with small files works fine. Someone know how to fix this? or any script to get file size.

The problem is io.seek, because the program open file without problem, and i can seek to a position lower than 2147483647 (just 1 byte less than 2GB), but when i try to see to 2GB or bigger position then fails.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It depends on Lua version and OS.

```
-- Program
print(io.open[[D:\_Best Films\The Grudge 1,2\Proklyatie.2004.x264.BDRip.720p.mkv]]:seek'end')

-- Output on Lua 5.2.1 / Windows
5706609998

-- Output on Lua 5.1.4 / Windows
nil     Invalid argument        22
```

The is no pure Lua workaround for this issue.

Comment: Program uses Lua 5.1.4 engine, maybe that's the problem... I'll try to make a dll to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is causing the particular error in your code but if I wanted to know the size of a file I would use the [LuaFilesystem](http://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html#reference) library. Its not part of the basic Lua standard libraries but its the most commonly used filesystem library I know. It comes bundled with the LuaForWindows distribution and is also easy to install with Luarocks.

```
local lfs = require 'lfs'

function getFileSize(filename)
   local attrs = lfs.attributes(filename)
   if not attrs then error("File not found") end
   return attrs.size
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i'm using a  program that use lua as scripting language, and i cannot install a 3rd party library.

Comment: @DanielCarrascoMarín: Then perhaps you can use a system-specific solution instead of a cross-platform library. The os.execute command can be used to run other programs and depending on how your system is configured perhaps there is some function available that does what you want.

Comment: I found a way to use lfs in the program i use, but i want to read last 16KB of file, and i don't know how to do it without io.open and seek. I didn't see how to do it with lfs.